The term 'AFDiag.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
I have a simple powershell script that executes afdiag.exe with a few parameters.
Example:
AFDiag.exe /Database:"Distributed SYS_Test" /Template:"STS-Heartbeat" /DelEF:"2024-06-01 00:00:00";"2024-06-03 15:00:00"

However it seems to reject the command I'm thinking to the way it's reading it in. I have tried several methods including set-location so as to just afdiag.exe without the path and it still fails. My two eyes can't see where I've gone wrong.
Code
# Define paths and parameters
$AFDiagPath = "D:\Program Files\PIPC\AF\AFDiag.exe"
$TemplatesFile = "D:\Scripts\PI AF Monthly Cleanup\cfg\PIAF MDB Cleanup Templates.csv"
$AFDatabase = "Distributed SYS_Test"
$OutputFolder = "D:\Scripts\PI AF Monthly Cleanup\log"

# Calculate date range (today and last 30 days)
$EndDate = Get-Date
$StartDate = $EndDate.AddDays(-30)

# Format dates for AFDiag
$StartDateFormatted = $StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$EndDateFormatted = $EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

# Read template names from CSV file
$TemplateNames = Import-Csv -Path $TemplatesFile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AFTemplates

# Create a timestamp for the log file
$Timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"
$LogFileName = "piaf-mdbc-log-$Timestamp.txt"
$LogFile = Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $LogFileName

# Iterate through template names and execute AFDiag command
foreach ($TemplateName in $TemplateNames) {
    # $AFDiagCommand = "AFDiag.exe /Database:`"$AFDatabase`" /Template:`"$TemplateName`" /DelEF:`"$StartDateFormatted`";`"$EndDateFormatted`""
    $AFDiagCommand = "$AFDiagPath /Database:`"$AFDatabase`" /Template:`"$TemplateName`" /DelEF:`"$StartDateFormatted`";`"$EndDateFormatted`""
    $Result = Invoke-Expression $AFDiagCommand

    # Append result to the log file
    $Result | Out-File -Append -FilePath $LogFile
}

# Display a message
Write-Host "AFDiag commands executed. Results logged in $LogFile"

This is the error generated
AFDiag.exe : The term 'AFDiag.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ AFDiag.exe /Database:"Distributed SYS_Test" /Template:"STS-Heartbea ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (AFDiag.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


whats the point of using Invoke-Expression when you can invoke the external command with & $AFDiagPath /Database:"$AFDatabase"...

@SantiagoSquarzon because whether or not I use "&", "Invoke-Expression" or "Start-Process I still get the same "The term blah-blah is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet error. I think it's the way I constructed the command and not necessarily the switched. Moreover, I need to pass the results to a log file and if possible, prefer to keep the "Invoke-Expression" or "Start-Process" switch.

does Test-Path -LiteralPath $AFDiagPath provide a True return?

@AbrahamZinala It actually does!

and does cmd /c $AFDiagPath give you any different error?

Does this answer your question? exe file not found by using powershell script

Updated code to leverage "Set-Location" to get around dealing with path issues involving blanks with "Program Files(x)". This seemed to resolve the issue once and for all.
Set-Location -Path "D:\Program Files\PIPC\AF\"
$AFDiagPath = ".\AFDiag.exe"


Your question has been answered here exe file not found by using powershell script
It is mandatory by PowerShell that you have to reference the parent folder of the external command when you call it. And more specifically, when you call external commands residing in the working directory, you must reference the folder in the command by a .\, at least. So, even when you Set-Location to afdiag.exe's parent folder, you should call it this way .\afdiag.exe.
Or, you can add the parent directory to the PATH Environment Variable before you invoke the command (if you do not want to reference the parent folder when you call the command). This configuration will last for the time of the session. The advantage is that you can call the command from another location.
$Env:Path = "path\to\parent\directory\;$Env:Path"
$AFDiagPath = 'AFDiag.exe'

You can add the parent path to the Environment variable Path in the OS [here Windows] System configurations or in the PowerShell profile script to make it permanent.
